# Why the value I pass to a function behaves like a pointer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I have this function :

```
static calculatePrice(offer)
{
    if (typeof (offer.TakerGets || offer.taker_gets) == "string")
        offer.quality = 1 / offer.quality;

    return offer.quality / 1000000;
}
```

I don't understand why the function modifies the value that I pass to it (`this.book[currency][side][this.j[currency][side]]`). It does not modify a copy but the original as if I had passed it a pointer.

Comment: That's how JavaScript works. Objects are passed as references, they're not copied.

Comment: JS never makes copies of objects or arrays by itself, you have to write it explicitly if you want a copy.

Comment: This is actually quite the interesting question, JavaScript is actually not pass-by-reference apparently, but it would affect the original object in your case. You can find a very nice detailed answer in this duplicate: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/13927534)

Comment: You should use `===` rather than `==` and also check `offer.quality` is non-zero before division.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, so fast! Actually, since the object is a value of a property, I didn't understand why it was doing this, but it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object into a function (or assign it from one variable to another), you're passing a value that's called an *object reference*, which tells JavaScript where the object is in memory.  *(Yes, it's a **bit** like a pointer in some other languages.)* You're not passing in a copy of the object. So yes, the function can change the state of that object by modifying its properties, etc.

Let's take a simpler example:

```js
function example(arg) {
    arg.answer = 42;     // Modifies the state of the object
}

let obj = {};
example(obj);            // Passes a value to the function saying where the
                         // object is in memory
console.log(obj.answer); // 42
```

In that code, the `example` function can modify the properties of the object, because what was passed in is an object reference.

It's important to note that JavaScript is still purely pass-by-value, it's just that the value being passed is an object reference. What the `example` function **can't** do is change the `obj` variable that was used in `example(obj)` by assigning a different object to `arg` (`arg = someOtherObject`.) Doing that only affects `arg`, not `obj`. (There's no link from `arg` back to `obj`, they both just have the same value in them.)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe this *is* a duplicate of [*Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) I thought a more targeted answer was called for, but others may decide to close the question, which is fair enough.

Comment: Oh yes, your last point is important to know.